# Is Rumplestiltskin immortal?

Tags: magic, once-upon-a-time

Is Rumplestiltskin immortal except for his dagger? Or is he killable but if you kill him with the dagger you gain the Dark One's powers?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the episode Fall which just aired November 30th, Rumplestiltskin confirmed in his comments to the Snow Queen that he is immortal. Too, that he would use that immortal life to be her enemy.  He uses that threat to bargain with the Snow Queen to allow Belle and Henry to leave Storybrooke with him to escape the curse she is about to cast.

[Wiki Episode Guide Season 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_(season_4)#Episodes)

**Note, in this context Immortal does not mean the same as Invulnerable.** I.e. we have always known that the dagger can not only be used to control the Dark Lord, but to kill him and transferring its powers. That is why he wants to use the hat to remove that "kryptonite" weakness.

Too, as ComicFan7794 noted, we also know that Dreamshade can kill Rumplestiltskin. as per "The Queen Is Dead" is the fifteenth episode of Season Two".

Hence, if the question is, "Can Rumplestiltskin be killed by items other than the dagger, the answer is also "Yes"." If the question is, "will he not die of old age" then again per canon the answer is "Yes", at least as stated directly by Rumplestiltskin, assuming he was not lying when he said it simply to try and gain an agreement :-)

I believe it would be an open question without canon support to know whether Rumplestiltskin/Gold could succumb to a disease. One might think with magic that he would be able to protect himself against such an outcome.

[Wikia Guide](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/The_Queen_Is_Dead)

Comment: Immortal could mean ageless though as Dreamshade was effective on him.And Cora confirmed if dark one is not killed by dagger the power could scatter so he must be killable with other items its just easier with dagger. I think he wants to remove dagger so it cant be used on him/ control him.

Comment: Agreed. I generally don't consider Immortal to be the same as Invulnerable. I take it as "ageless".